# Android App streaming video using wifi direct

Tags: android, sockets, wifi, wifi-direct

I'm currently working on an app that will stream video from one phone, to another using wifi-direct.

I've already installed and tested the sample wifi-direct app that comes with the SDK. It works great sending images from one Nexus 4 to another.

Some problems I've experienced:

I tried to have the app send a video by changing the "image/*" string to "video/*" wherever it appeared. And ".jpg" to ".mp4".

After running the app with these changes, I am still able to connect devices, but one N4 is stuck at "Opening a server socket". And the video I took never gets sent.

Perhaps I went about it wrong.

Regardless, my real goal is to stream video from one phone to the other using wifi-direct only (no data connection / wifi).

Could someone help me figure out what steps I should pursue in order to accomplish this? Should I start with the wifi-direct sample app as a base? Or should I try to write it from scratch myself? How should I go about streaming the video using wifi-direct?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your min Android SDK?

Comment: 4.0 I believe, maybe 4.1. But I will change it to whatever necessary just to create the proof of concept.

Comment: Take a look at this: https://github.com/fyhertz/libstreaming and: http://www.roman10.net/how-to-build-ffmpeg-for-android/

Comment: do you have any example code for your work?